# Maxlength on input type="number" Parlsey.js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input, parsley.js

I am trying to limit the numbers on input type number with Parsley.js but this doesn't work:

```
<input type="number" name="" maxlength="2" data-parsley-maxlength='2'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding max and min:

For floats

```html
<input type="text" min="1" max="999" data-parsley-type="number" pattern="\d*" />
```

For whole numbers

```html
<input type="text" min="1" max="999" data-parsley-type="digits" pattern="\d*" />
```

Comment: I am using Parsley.js

Comment: You could try using input type text and add the attribute data-parsley-type="digits"

Comment: Yes, the problem is that if i put type text, it will not enable the numeric keyboard on mobile

Comment: You could try adding pattern="\d*" or pattern='\d+'

Comment: Thank you, i will test it to see how it is supported